# How does Numpy move data when transpose a matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

It seems numpy.transpose only save strides, and do actually transpose lazily according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034237/how-does-numpys-transpose-method-permute-the-axes-of-an-array/32034565#32034565)

So, when data movement actually happened and how to move? use many many `memcpy`? or some other trick?

I follow the path:
[`array_reshape`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.13.x/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c#L172),
[`PyArray_Newshape`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.13.x/numpy/core/src/multiarray/shape.c#L189),
[`PyArray_NewCopy`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.13.x/numpy/core/src/multiarray/convert.c#L579),
[`PyArray_NewLikeArray`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.13.x/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L1167),
`PyArray_NewFromDescr`,
`PyArray_NewFromDescrAndBase`,
[`PyArray_NewFromDescr_int`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.13.x/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L900)
but see nothing about axis permute. When did it happen indeed?

---

Update 2021/1/19

Thanks for answers, numpy array copy with transpose is [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.19.5/numpy/core/src/multiarray/array_assign_array.c#L133), which use a common [macro](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.19.5/numpy/core/src/common/lowlevel_strided_loops.h#L565) to implement it, this algorithm is very native, and it does not consider any of simd acceleration or cache friendliness

Comment: Data is copied from the source array according to its strides to the allocated target according to its strides.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you for comment, could you tell me the code about it? I want to know about its algorithm of transpose.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is: `Numpy` doesn't move data.

Did you see `PyArray_Transpose` on line [688](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/a3bb8f83de6f0fe3d0dfa14b9bfe1889f9b45652/numpy/core/src/multiarray/shape.c#L688) of your above links? There is a permute in this function,

```
    n = permute->len;
    axes = permute->ptr;
    ...
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int axis = axes[i];
        ...
        permutation[i] = axis;
}
```

Any array shape is purely metadata, used by `Numpy` to understand how to handle the data, as memory is always stored linearly and contiguously. There is therefore no reason to move or reorder any data, from the docs [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/97c35365beda55c6dead8c50df785eb857f843f0/numpy/doc/internals.py#L43),

> Other operations, such as transpose, don't move data elements
>   around in the array, but rather change the information about the shape and strides so that the indexing of the array changes, but the data in the doesn't move.
>   Typically these new versions of the array metadata but the same data buffer are
>   new 'views' into the data buffer. There is a different ndarray object, but it
>   uses the same data buffer. This is why it is necessary to force copies through
>   use of the .copy() method if one really wants to make a new and independent
>   copy of the data buffer.

The only reason to copy may be to maximize [cache efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_interchange#The_utility_of_loop_interchange), although `Numpy` already [considers](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/97c35365beda55c6dead8c50df785eb857f843f0/numpy/doc/internals.py#L135) this,

> As it turns out, numpy is smart enough when dealing with ufuncs to determine which index is the most rapidly varying one in memory and uses that for the innermost loop.

Comment: I know `np.transpose` call will not move data, but `reshape` or `copy` after it **will** move data indeed. so where is the code moving data when I call `reshape`?

Comment: @HaoZhang under `alloc.c`, on line 221 is `result = malloc(size);` (https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.c). The word "move" is a bit odd here, I assume `Numpy` will allocate a new data array in `np.copy` with `PyDataMem_NEW` and then fill it with your copied array values, before setting/copying the permutation/array shape metadata.

Comment: Also. see this https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/aef982e4482773e802cc0ef076bf5e76ff650cf9/numpy/core/src/multiarray/array_assign_array.c#L225 for copying arrays

Answer (score 1):

Tracing through the `numpy` C code is a slow and tedious process.  I prefer to deduce patterns of behavior from timings.

Make a sample array and its transpose:

```
In [168]: A = np.random.rand(1000,1000)
In [169]: At = A.T
```

First a fast view - no coping of the databuffer:

```
In [171]: timeit B = A.ravel()
262 ns ± 4.39 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

A fast copy (presumably uses some fast block memory coping):

```
In [172]: timeit B = A.copy()
2.2 ms ± 26.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

A slow copy (presumably requires traversing the source in its strided order, and the target in its own order):

```
In [173]: timeit B = A.copy(order='F')
6.29 ms ± 2.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Copying `At` without having to change the order - fast:

```
In [174]: timeit B = At.copy(order='F')
2.23 ms ± 51.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Like [173] but going from 'F' to 'C':

```
In [175]: timeit B = At.copy(order='C')
6.29 ms ± 4.16 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [176]: timeit B = At.ravel()
6.54 ms ± 214 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Copies with simpler strided reordering fall somewhere in between:

```
In [177]: timeit B = A[::-1,::-1].copy()
3.75 ms ± 4.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [178]: timeit B = A[::-1].copy()
3.73 ms ± 6.48 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [179]: timeit B = At[::-1].copy(order='K')
3.98 ms ± 212 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

This `astype` also requires the slower copy:

```
In [182]: timeit B = A.astype('float128')
6.7 ms ± 8.12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

`PyArray_NewFromDescr_int` is described as `Generic new array creation routine.`  While I can't figure out where it copies data from the source to the target, it clearly is checking `order` and `strides` and `dtype`.  Presumably it handles all cases where the generic copy is required.  The axis permutation isn't a special case.