# Time complexity of numpy.transpose

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

What is the time-complexity of np.transpose?

In my opinion, it loops two for loops inside so, that means it should have O(n2) complexity but can someone confirm on that?
Also, is there any way so, that I can reduce the time-complexity of matrix transpose

Comment: As others noted, a numpy transpose just changes a couple of parameters, not the whole data buffer.  But subsequent use of the transposed array might require a copy, which will roughly depend on the total number of elements.  But in general the `numpy` approach to handling dimensions is flexible and efficient - don't be afraid to take full advantage of its features.

Answer (score 16):

In memory the matrices are represented as blocks of contiguous memory, that is as if it were a one-dimensional array. N-dimensions are an abstraction that we humans use to make the problem more understandable. For numpy, transposing the matrix is ​​simply an axis change, but the memory is not changed.

So the temporal complexity is **O(1)** because to transpose an array, numpy just swaps the shape and stride information for each axis.

No data needs to be copied for this to happen. Numpy can simply change how it looks at the underlying memory to construct the new array.

If you want to deepen the topic you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32034565/9302488) beautiful answer with illustrations

Comment: As someone who is a physical scientist first and a computer scientist second, "N-dimensions are an abstraction that we humans use to make the problem more understandable." is . . hilarious on so many levels.

Comment: Hilarious on as many levels as there are dimensions in the `ndarray`?

Comment: The above answer applies to the numpy `reshape` operation as well.

Answer (score 11):

It is O(1), because it does not copy data at all.  Just modifies the shape and strides.

```
>>> A = np.random.rand(3,4)
>>> A.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
>>> np.transpose(A).flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

Note that `C_CONTIGUOUS`, `F_CONTIGUOUS` were swapped (i.e. major iteration order changes), and the transposed array has `OWNDATA` false (i.e. it is just a *view* into the original array's data).

*Related tip:* when you have a view like this, to find the array owning the data you can check the `base` attribute

```
>>> np.transpose(A).base is A
True
```

Comment: I'd say it modifies `shape` and `strides`.  The flags change is an indirect effect of changing strides.  I think `A.__array_interface__` is a better indicator than `flags`.

Comment: Well however you want to look at it.  The main point is that the array data is not copied by a transpose.

Answer (score -2):

Yes adding to that we can also transpose matrix by using zip

```
list(zip(*matrix))
```

Comment: That's not a `numpy` answer.

Comment: that's true but as I mentioned in my question that I was looking for any other way to transpose the matrix(not necessarily numpy).
I found this one so, shared.

Comment: I didn't notice that you'd answered your own question.  If you start with a list of lists, then this probably the best way of doing a 'transpose'.  I wouldn't use it if `matrix` is already a `numpy` array.  `numpy` can change the order of axes simply by changing the `strides`; no copy is needed.