# scatter matrix column wise

Tags: numpy, mpi, mpi4py

I am trying to scatter matrix of size N x N column wise to different processes. Its expected that N % number_of_processes = 0. Input matrix:

A = 
[[1,2,3,4],
[5,6,7,8], 
[9,10,11,12],
[13,14,15,16]
] 
When I run this with 2 processes, process P0 should receive columns 1-2: [[1,5,9,13], [2,6,10,14]], P1 should receive columns 3-4 [[3,7,11,15], [4,8,12,16]]. I transposed the matrix so each row of the new matrix is consists of columns, but when scattering still receiving rows in the order of original matrix.

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

N = 4
#K = 10


if rank == 0:
    A = np.random.random((N,N))/N*2
    vector = np.random.random(N)
    print("Rank: ", rank)
    print("A: ", A)
    print("Vector: ", vector)
else:
    A=np.empty((N,N), dtype='float64')
    vector = np.empty(N, dtype='float64')

# distributing vector to all processes
#comm.Bcast(vector, root = 0)

matrix_columns = np.empty((A.shape[0],A.shape[0]), dtype='float64')

# get columns from matrix
if rank == 0:
    matrix_columns = np.transpose(A)
else:
    matrix_columns = np.empty((A.shape[0],A.shape[0]), dtype='float64')

if rank == 0:
    print("Columns >>>")
    print(matrix_columns)

# distribute columns to all processes
received_columns = np.empty((matrix_columns.shape[0]//size,matrix_columns.shape[0]), dtype='float64')


comm.Scatter(matrix_columns, received_columns, root = 0)


print("My rank: ", rank,  "received columns: ", received_columns)
```

Comment: it seems `np.transpose(A)` took a shorcut and did not transpose the matrix (!) Instead, it hacked the "metadata" to tell python `matrix_columns` should be interpreted as a Fortran matrix (instead of a C matrix like `A`). This can be evidenced by `print(A.flags)` and `print(matrix_columns.flags)`.

Comment: see the answer with 10 votes at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58279082/time-complexity-of-numpy-transpose