# Understanding Numpy dimensions of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I started looking into Numpy using a 'Python for data analysis'. Why is the array dimension for arr2d is "2", instead of "3". Also why is the dimension for arr3d "3", instead of "2".

I thought the dimension of the array is based on the number of rows? Or this doesn't apply to higher dimensional and multidimensional arrays?

`arr2d = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])`

`arr2d.shape`

Output: (3, 3)

`arr2d.ndim`

Output: 2

`arr3d = np.array([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]])`

`arr3d.shape`

Output: (2, 2, 3)

`arr3d.ndim`

Output: 3

Comment: You're thinking of the dimensionality of the space the data points are drawn from, not the dimensionality of the array itself.

Comment: Also, a 3D array doesn't have rows. That's a 2D concept.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica could you please explain further ?

Comment: The number of dimensions is equal to the number of values in `shape`, which you can see in the outputs. `arr2d` contains 3 * 3 = 6 numbers, `arr3d` contains 2 * 2 * 3 = 12 numbers.

Comment: @myrmica Thanks for the explanation, I now understand what you're saying. You get the dimension based on the shape. if the shape of an array n is ```(4,4)```, then it's dimension is '2' and if an array b has a shape of ```(2,3,4)```, then it's dimension is '3'.

Comment: A general analogy might be: `np.array([1,2,3])` is like a line and has one dimension;   `np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])` is like a plane and has two dimensions;  `np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]])` is like a cube and has three dimension.

Comment: Maybe a visual representation would be helpful. I have added a basic intuitive answer to your question (with some advanced knowledge around strides if you are interested).

Answer (score 0):

well see basically the dimension of the array is not based on the number of rows
basically it is based on the `brackets` i.e `[]` that you entered in `np.array()` method

see

`arr2d = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])`

in `arr2d` there are `2 brackets([[]])` or there are 2 opening `brackets([[)` or its has 2 closing `brackets(]])` so its an `2D array` of `(3,3)` i.e 3 rows and 3 columns

similarly

`arr3d = np.array([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]])`

in `arr3d` there are `3 brackets([[[]]])` or there are 3 opening `brackets([[[)` or or its has 3 closing `brackets(]]])`  so its an `3D array` of `(2,2,3)` i.e its has 2 arrays of 2 rows and 3 columns

Answer (score 0):

Numpy stores its ndarrays as contiguous blocks of memory. Each element is stored in a sequential manner every n bytes after the previous.

(images referenced from this [excellent SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034237/how-does-numpys-transpose-method-permute-the-axes-of-an-array))

So if your 3D array looks like this  -

```
np.arange(0,16).reshape(2,2,4)

#array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#        [ 4,  5,  6,  7]],
#
#       [[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
#        [12, 13, 14, 15]]])
```

[image]

Then in memory its stores as -

[image]

When retrieving an element (or a block of elements), NumPy calculates how many `strides` (of 8 bytes each) it needs to traverse to get the next element `in that direction/axis`. So, for the above example, for `axis=2` it has to traverse 8 bytes (depending on the `datatype`) but for `axis=1` it has to traverse `8*4` bytes, and `axis=0` it needs `8*8` bytes.

With this in mind, let's understand what dimensions are in numpy.

```
arr2d = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
arr3d = np.array([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]])
print(arr2d.shape, arr3d.shape)
```

```
(3, 3) (2, 2, 3)
```

These can be considered a 2D matrix and a 3D tensor respectively. Here is an intuitive diagram to show how this would look like.

[image]

A 1D numpy array with (ndims=1) is a vector, 2D is a matrix, and 3D is a rank 2 tensor which can be imagined as a cube. The number of values it can store is equal to - `array.shape[0] * array.shape[1] * array.shape[2]` which in your second case is `2*2*3`.

```
Vector (n,)       -> (axis0,)                #elements
Matrix (m,n)      -> (axis0, axis1)          #rows, columns
Tensor2 (l,m,n)   -> (axis0, axis1, axis2)
Tensor3 (l,m,n,o) -> (axis0, axis1, axis2, axis3)
```