# Can someone explain how numpy displays multidimensional arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

given the following command:

```
np.ones((2,2,3))
```

I get the following

```
array([[[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]]])
```

From what I understand reading docos/blogs etc this is a multi-dimensional array that is effectively a combination of 3, 2x2 matrices so we have 2 columns 2 rows and "depth" dimension of 3 meaning numpy uses a (row,column,depth) system for 3 dimensional arrays.

How then should I interpret what is displayed in the terminal which appears to be 2 3x2 matrices implying a (depth,row,column) system.

Comment: Hmm, no, it's a combination of 2 2x3 matrices

Comment: It would also help to link to the relevant documentation that is confusing you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.
Research first, then post.  Read the documentation.  Work through a tutorial.  Look at an example with unique values.

Comment: having reread the documentation I have realised that it supports your comment and that actually my university project and a number of stack questions are misleading.

Comment: Kinda depends on which direction you are looking from... `a[...,0], a[...,1], a[...,2]` are all 2x2 arrays.  A bit problematic portraying a 3-d structure on a plane with text.

Comment: MATLAB displays it as 3 2x2 planes.  But in numpy the first dimension is outermost (normally)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike Matlab (which is column-major) NumPy uses [row-major indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order): grouping starts from the leftmost index. So, `ones((2, 3, 4))` consists of two arrays that are `ones((3, 4))`, and each of those consists of three arrays that are `ones((4,))`.

Left - to - right is outer - to - inner. Also, it is slowly-changing index - to - quickly-changing index (if one reads all the elements sequentially).

```
>>> np.ones((2, 3, 4))
array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]])
```

For a 2D array it's row-column. For 3D it is depth-row-column, etc: for 4D it's something-something-row-column.