# Sanity Check on Numpy Dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy

Just wanted to make sure I'm seeing what I'm seeing in numpy. 
In english terms, I want to create an array with a height of 2, width of 3, and a depth of four.

I would assume that the shape would be (2,3,4) following logical order, but when I create the array, the shape turns out to be (4,2,3).

```
some = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], [[5,6,7],[8,9,10]],[[5,6,7],[8,9,10]],[[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]])
# some.shape = (4,2,3), not what I expect (2,3,4)
```

Can someone explain how the dimensions are ordered in python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [3-dimensional array in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981845/3-dimensional-array-in-numpy)

Comment: Look at a piece, `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` - that's a list of 2 items, each with 3 items.  That makes an array with shape (2,3).  That pattern generalizes to 3d.  Your `some` has 4 such blocks.  If that doesn't make sense, then explain why your expectation is more logical.

Comment: @hpaulj So to clarify, in english with Height H, Width W, and Depth D, the shape is (D, H,W)? I understand that 2D is (H,W). I guess my question is what the shape of the 3D is, (D,H,W) or (H,W,D)? Or do I have a bad understanding of shapes and axes?

Comment: In numpy dimensions are ordered 0,1,2, ...  Names are somewhat arbitrary.  In 2d numpy arrays we often talk about rows and columns.  In 3d its safer to talk about panels, rows and columns, though the terminology isn't fixed.  `depth` isn't a common `numpy` term, though `np.dstack` talks about the 3rd dimension as `depth`.  Look at its docs, and compare it to `hstack` (horizontal) and `vstack`  (vertical).

Comment: It is probably easier to think solely in terms of first, second and third dimension instead of  height width and depth. Width and height have to do with how things are printed, for instance `print(np.array([[1,2]]))` and `print(np.array([1,2]))` are both printed from left to right but the dimension differs. @hpaulj, indeed because of confusing terms np.stack is preferred now above hstack, vstack and dstack methods