# Why are 3D numpy arrays printed the way they are (How are they ordered)?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to wrap my head around 3D arrays (or multi-dimensional arrays in general), but it's blowing my brains a bit. Especially the way in which 3D numpy arrays are printed is counter-intuitive to me. This question is [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981845/3-dimensional-array-in-numpy) but it is more about the differences between programming languages, and I still do not fully get it.  Let me try to explain.

Say I want to create a 3D array with 3 rows (length), 5 columns(width) and 2 depth. So a 3x5x2 matrix.

I do the following:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros(30).reshape(3, 5, 2)
```

To me, a logical way to print this would be like this:

```
[[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]  #We can still see three rows from top to bottom
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]] #We can still see five columns from left to right

 [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]  #Depth values are shown underneath each other
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]] 

 [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]]
```

However, when I print this array it prints like this:

```
[[[0. 0.] #We can still see three rows from top to bottom,
  [0. 0.] #However columns now also appear from top to bottom instead of from left to right
  [0. 0.] #Depth values are now shown from left to right
  [0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]]]
```

It is unobvious to me why the array would be printed in this way. Maybe it is just me (Maybe my spatial reasoning is lacking here), or is there a specific reason why NumPy arrays are printed like this?

Comment: 3x5x2 means you have 3 arrays of shape 5x2. That is what you see. 3 here  is the depth. The first array is 5 rows 2 columns (5x2), the second array is 5 rows 2 columns (5x2), and the third array is 5 rows 2 columns (5x2). The array is printed layer wise

Comment: Possible duplicate of [3-dimensional array in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981845/3-dimensional-array-in-numpy)

Comment: You'd get your expected result with `reshape(3, 2, 5)`

Comment: @Bazingaa So the first value in `numpy.reshape()` is always depth? So would it be something like `numpy.reshape(depth, rows, columns)`? The second answer in the dupe you flag states `numpy.zeros(2,3,4)`  Generates a matrix *with 2 rows, 3 columns and 4 depth*, so I am still a bit confused.

Comment: @Barmar @Barmar I figured yes, but to me that would be a more logical way to print a (3,5,2) matrix, as then the original spatial ordering of rows and columns remains "as is", while printing it like the way it does now you basically "Swap" the column dimension from horizontal to vertical. All of this is assuming of course that `np.zeros(30).reshape(3, 5, 2)` generates a matrix with 3 rows, 5 columns and 2 depth, which, based on above comments, might be a faulty assumption?

Comment: First, take a look at `np.zeroes(10).reshape(5, 2)`. That's 5 rows of 2 columns, not 2 rows of 5 columns. Adding `3` at the front means 3 planes of 5 rows and 2 columns.

Comment: What you're missing is that you new dimension is at the *front*, not the end.

Comment: @Barmar I see... so what you're saying is when I use np.reshape() for adding a dimension (say from 2D to 3D), I should always add the extra dimension *at the front*? Do you know why this could be? Because in mathematics, usually the extra dimensions are added at the end (Like extending an (x,y) with a z becomes (x,y,z)

Comment: This is how array dimensions are typically done in computer science. It reflects the way arrays are typically stored in row-major order in memory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order

Comment: Thx, did not know this & clarifies a lot.

Comment: If you craft this response into a proper answer - I'll make sure to accept it

Comment: See "axis" in the [numpy glossary of terms](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/glossary.html#term-axis). (Skim through the whole glossary -- it's really well-written.)

Comment: The question is already answered, but I guess visual representation helps. See this [medium post](https://towardsdatascience.com/reshaping-numpy-arrays-in-python-a-step-by-step-pictorial-tutorial-aed5f471cf0b).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Synthesizing the comments into a proper answer:

First, take a look at `np.zeros(10).reshape(5, 2)`. That's 5 rows of 2 columns, not 2 rows of 5 columns. Adding 3 at the front means 3 planes of 5 rows and 2 columns. What you're missing is that you new dimension is at the *front*, not the end. In mathematics, usually the extra dimensions are added at the end (Like extending an (x,y) with a z becomes (x,y,z). However, in computer science array dimensions are typically done this way. It reflects the way arrays are typically stored in row-major order in memory.